# Adding custom button to CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I've downloaded the 'timestamp' plugin example, but no matter what I do, I can't get the new button to appear in my toolbar. Otherwise, CKEditor seems to work great.

My config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

config.extraPlugins = 'timestamp';

config.toolbar = [
    { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic','Underline','Strike' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList' ] },
    { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink' ] },
];

config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:advanced;link:target';
```

};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you cleared browser cache. also add the button where you want it to go

```
config.toolbar = [
    { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'TimeStamp', 'Italic','Underline','Strike' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList' ] },
    { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink' ] },
];
```